# How can we filter our "Saves" by tag?

Tags: support, tags, search, filtering, saves

I am using [the new "Saves" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)  to save references to coding questions and/or hints about specific libraries. As a novice, I find it really helpful as a way to store and retrieve basic rules and tricks. However, I find that as I accumulate more and more "Saves", it is difficult to find the relevant ones.

It would be nice to be able to filter "Saves" by tag. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `in:saves` together with the tag in the search box, i.e.

```
in:saves [google-apps-script]
```

The above will return the questions having [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) that you saved.

Reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: what about lists inside saves ? (I'll give you brownie points for that !!!) Thanks indeed

Comment: I'm sorry, AFAIK, there is no search operator for saves lists yet.

Comment: @pippo1980 [not planned right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves#comment1274236_382024) but hopefully in the future.

Comment: @VLAZ the comment anchor doesn't work for me. I really hope they get that implemented - I would think that part of the reason for having lists at all is so that one can make, e.g., a list of canonicals on a particular topic, and then easily find them.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The link in the above comment [works for me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1274236) - in any case, it links to a comment below VLAZ' answer (or feature request): [Allow for searching in specific lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382024).